# Program is not executing in python

Tags: python, correlation

I am using a book for learning python :

There is a file recommendations.py in which I have all this code

When I execute command on command line

```
reload(recommendations)
>>> recommendations.sim_distance(recommendations.critics,
... 'Lisa Rose','Gene Seymour')
```

It gives me following error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    reload(recommendations)
   NameError: name 'recommendations' is not defined
```

Comment: do - `import recommendations` .

Comment: THANKS SIR :) Solved

Comment: @Kims  please accept the answer then ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to import `recommendations` before running your script.